# clang seems to ignore debug information from object files in static libraries

Tags: linker, clang, static-linking, debug-symbols

When I link my final binary directly from the object files, as in

```
clang -o binary build/lib/*.o build/bin/*.o
```

and my binary crashes, I have line numbers everywhere, because all my object files were build with `-g`, so I should get full debug info.

But when I combine some of the object files to a static library, using

```
ar -q lib.a build/lib/*.o
```

and then link the final binary with

```
clang -o binary lib.a build/bin/*.o
```

and I get a crash, I only have line numbers for the object files but no line numbers for any object file from within the static library.

What am I doing wrong?

### Update

I figured out that it has something to do with symlinks. The example commands I provided were simplified, the real link command uses absolute paths as in

```
clang -o binary /symlink/to/lib.a /fullpath/to/build/bin/*.o
```

The problem is the symlink path. When I instead use the absolute path to lib.a that contains no symlinks, then everything works as expected and I get line numbers. Also when I'm within the folder of `lib.a` and use no path at all, just the filename, it works as expected. Only when addressing the library via a symlink it fails.

BTW, the platform is macOS Sonoma, the clang version is the one that came with Xcode 14.3.1 (`clang-1403.0.22.14.1`).

Comment: What tool do you use to _get_ the line numbers? The problem is more likely with that tool than with the linker (which shouldn't care at all).

Comment: @EmployedRussian The system crash reporter but also LLDB when printing stack traces. I compared the symbol tables of two binaries, one that produces line numbers and one that doesn't and the only difference I was able to find is that one contains paths with and one contains paths without symlink, yet bot are valid paths and point to exactly the same files. And I cannot reproduce it with a minimal test case and another path with symlink. I can only reproduce it with this one specific source build in this one specific build location.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

You didn't say what platform you are on, or which linker you are using.

For UNIX linkers other than LLD, this command:

```
clang -o binary lib.a build/bin/*.o
```

will result in *no* objects from `lib.a` actually being used.

Normally this would result in unresolved symbols, but (depending on which symbols are defined in `lib.a`) the symbols may come from the `libc` system library, and in that case you may in fact get the "no line numbers".

The command you want is:

```
clang -o binary build/bin/*.o lib.a
```

The order of command line arguments on the link line [matters](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking).

Comment: "You didn't say what platform you are on, or which linker you are using." - Isn't that abstracted by clang? Isn't it up to clang to make the correct link command for the platform it is running on, that performs the link operation I requested from clang? Otherwise I could call the linker directly, what advantage would it have to go over clang? The platform is macOS.

Comment: And the symbols in the library are used for sure as that's where the crash is and linking would fail to begin with without those symbols. And to my knowledge that isn't macOS specific, it works the same in Linux. And changing the order has zero effect whatsoever.

Comment: And also using `-L<libdir> -l<libname>` makes no difference either. The symbols are always found but the debug information is missing for those symbols despite it being present in the .o files inside the library.